Is there support for syntax highlighting for dmesg kernel log output in KDE's Kate text editor?
Is there support for syntax highlighting for dmesg kernel log output in KDE's Kate text editor?
I looked for it in Kate version 22.12.3 from Debian 12 (Bullworm) stable but didn't find anything suitable or if there is something I missed it. If there is something suitable, can someone tell me where I can find it in Kate?
Or could it be that one of the later Kate versions has support for the dmesg kernel output?
Dmesg itself has at least a five-color output.

Green for the time.
brown or dark orange for the device category.
gray for the normal text.
white for important warnings
and red for errors.

Now I'm looking for something similar for Kate.

Kate could reinvent the wheel (and maybe it does), but IMO a good general approach would be if we could enable interpreting ANSI color codes and such. Then we could just dmesg --color=always | kate --stdin and the colors would simply come from dmesg. I haven't found such functionality in/for Kate though.
